# How to read specific file in a tree structure?

Tags: python, file, treeview

I would like to read (possibly csv) files in a tree. I have the code to create the tree and select the item in it but could not find a way to show file's contents on a text area. The code segment below selects the item and inserts the name to the text area so the rest should be fit in here I suppose.

```
from Tkinter import*
import ttk

def _select(self, event):
    item = self.tree.selection()[0]
    self.textArea.insert(INSERT, "Reading: "+ self.tree.item(item,"text") + "\n")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to read the contents of the file, you could do:

```
filename = self.tree.item(item,"text")
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
    self.textArea.insert(INSERT, line)
```

Give it a shot and let us know how it goes!

Comment: Bear in mind that's very simplified and will probably break  with all sorts of unusual cases - binary data or weird encodings, very large files etc.